# Page Element only appearing on mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, css

I am building a WordPress website and there is a second navigation box that is only displayed on small mobile devices. I cannot figure out for the life of me how to get rid of it. I am unable to find out what it even is due to a lack of page inspection tools on android.

mangapunch.com is the website and I use a Samsung Galaxy S3 to get a feel for small mobile devices so if you do any checking I would suggest a similarly sized android phone.

I would love an explanation for why it is there and what causes it to exist.

Comment: the page changes drastically on mobile so there must be code all over the place checking the user agent and possibly media queries checking the screen size. its probably a "feature" of your wordpress theme, you should check its documentation

Comment: I have checked the documentation and I cannot find anything on it but perhaps you are in the right place about checking the user agent I will look over the files in the theme.

Comment: Search in style.css for rules similar to `@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) and (min-width: 860px) #main-menu select { display: block; width: 240px; margin-left: 10px; }` (Or, remove the include from your files so its not delivered..)

Comment: How did you find those exact css rules? And thanks